# ArgumentOutOfRangeException while using XlsIO with Excel template

Tags: excel, windows-8, windows-runtime, syncfusion

I am using SyncFusion XlsIo for exporting data to excel sheet. I am having some problems while exporting data to excel. I think I have problems in excel template. So first of all I want to know how can I create template for excel, so I can place values there ? I want to do similar thing which is in sample app provided by SyncFusion SDK. I tried to replicate that excel template but it didn't work and threw exception. Exception details are given below.

> Exception : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user
>   code   HResult=-2146233086   Message=Can't find property Parameter
>   name: strText   Source=Syncfusion.XlsIO.WinRT   ParamName=strText
>   StackTrace:
>          at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.TemplateMarkers.TemplateMarkersImpl.GetNextValue(Object
>   value, String& strText, String& newNumberFormat,
>
> Type& newType)
>          at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.TemplateMarkers.TemplateMarkersImpl.SetSimpleValue(Object
>   value, String strText, IWorksheet sheet,
>
> IMigrantRange migrantRange, IList`1 arrMarkerCells, IList
>   lstArguments, MarkerOptionsImpl options, RangeBuilder builder,
>   UnknownVariableAction
>
> action, String numberFormat, Type valueType)
>          at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.TemplateMarkers.TemplateMarkersImpl.SetArrayValue(IList
>   value, String strText, IWorksheet sheet,
>
> IMigrantRange migrantRange, IList`1 arrMarkerCells, IList
>   lstArguments, MarkerOptionsImpl options, RangeBuilder builder,
>   UnknownVariableAction
>
> action, VariableTypeAction variableTypeAction)
>          at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.TemplateMarkers.TemplateMarkersImpl.SetUnknownVariable(Object
>   value, String strText, IWorksheet sheet,
>
> IMigrantRange migrantRange, IList`1 arrMarkerCells, IList
>   lstArguments, MarkerOptionsImpl options, RangeBuilder builder,
>   UnknownVariableAction
>
> action, VariableTypeAction variableTypeAction)
>          at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.TemplateMarkers.TemplateMarkersImpl.SetVariable(String
>   strVariable, String strText, IWorksheet sheet,
>
> IMigrantRange migrantRange, IList`1 arrMarkerCells, IList
>   lstArguments, MarkerOptionsImpl options, RangeBuilder builder,
>   UnknownVariableAction
>
> action)
>          at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.TemplateMarkers.TemplateMarkersImpl.ApplyMarker(IWorksheet
>   sheet, IList`1 arrCells, Int32 i, IMigrantRange
>
> migrantRange, UnknownVariableAction action)
>          at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.TemplateMarkers.TemplateMarkersImpl.ApplyMarkers(IWorksheet
>   sheet, List`1 arrLabels, UnknownVariableAction
>
> action)
>          at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.TemplateMarkers.TemplateMarkersImpl.ApplyMarkers(IWorkbook
>   book, UnknownVariableAction action)
>          at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Implementation.TemplateMarkers.TemplateMarkersImpl.ApplyMarkers(UnknownVariableAction
>   action)
>          at InvoiceExportDemo.ExportToExcel.d__0.MoveNext() in
>   d:\Projects\InvoiceExportDemo\InvoiceExportDemo\HelperClass
>
> \ExportToExcel.cs:line 29

line : `marker.ApplyMarkers(UnknownVariableAction.Skip);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is raised due to the usage issue. Custom class property name and marker in the input template should match. Use the following procedure to create input template with marker and refer the sample provided.

**Create input template with template marker:**

**Syntax :**
%classname.PropertyName

**Example :**
%InvoiceItem.ItemName

Represents the above string in the excel file then in the sample use the below code snippet.

```
List<InvoiceItem> items = new List<InvoiceItem>();
items.Add(new InvoiceItem("Essential Studio WinRT", 1, 399, 50));
items.Add(new InvoiceItem("Essential ASP.NET ", 1, 995, 70));
//Create Template Marker Processor
ITemplateMarkersProcessor marker = book.CreateTemplateMarkersProcessor();
//Binding the business object with the marker.
marker.AddVariable("InvoiceItem", items);

//Applies the marker.
marker.ApplyMarkers(UnknownVariableAction.Skip);
```

**Sample :** [Template_Marker_Sample.zip](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/Support/DirectTrac/General/TemplateMarkerSample949854884.zip)

Regards,

Johnson